# Make HTML form input hints that pops up with JavaScript accessible?

Tags: jquery, html, accessibility

Imagine I have a form with a hidden tip:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='name' placeholder='Name'>
    <span id="name_hint" style="display: none;">Please enter your name</span>
</form>
```

And jQuery pops up the tip when input value is invalid:

```
$('#name').on('blur', function(){
    if(!this.value.length) {
        $('#name_hint').show();
    }
});
```

When that user left the text input without entering anything how do I tell web reader to read content of hint that now visible hint?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`span` with a `tabindex` can get focused. By Adding `tabindex` to hint and focusing on it when input value is invalid we can force web reader to read popped up hint!

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='name' placeholder='Name'>
    <span id="name_hint" style="display: none;" tabindex="2">Please enter your name</span>
</form>


$('#name').on('blur', function(){
    if(!this.value.length) {
        $('#name_hint').show().get(0).focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question belongs more to ux.stackexchange.com,  but for starters I can recommend to:

- Make them stand out : use bright colors. Also, stick to the usual colors when it comes to a success/warning/error message (see how [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts) does it).
- Give the user the time to see them: use transitions effects. Maybe not super fancy stuff though. The user will always want to read something that would pop up under his nose, but he needs to notice it. Transition give the time for the user to see them.
- Make it clear it is related to the content the user is manipulating: maybe by having an arrow indicating that the pop up is related to the field on focus.

As if your concern is more for warning/error/important messages, I recommend to have a look a this [thread](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4260/do-users-read-pop-up-messages-notifications-error-messages-etc).

Answer (score 0):

For starters, form elements should really have `<label>`s to be truly accessible:

```
<form>
 <input type='text' id='name'>
  <label for='name'>Please enter your name</label>
</form>
```

The placeholder attribute, is [not a good subsitute for a label](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2011/02/html5-accessibility-chops-the-placeholder-attribute/). However if you want to use your method, it should be:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='name' placeholder='Name' aria-labelledby="name_hint">
    <span id="name_hint" style="display: none;">Please enter your name</span>
</form>
```

Then your JS should have an onFocus event also.